# Scaling TEST data which is not true representative of train data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I've built a model which I would like to test on unseen data. I feed the data in daily, which can have a different range everyday. For example, if I use `MinMaxScaler()`, I scale the training data to [0,1] interval.

Now, the maximum value in the training set is 100, which will be transformed to 1.

When my test data comes in daily, it could actually turn out that maximum value was actually 10, which would also be transformed to 1.

```
# min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
# df_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df.values)
```

I tried using normalisation instead, e.g. `df_norm = (df - df.mean()) / (df.max() - df.min())`, and then using these values on the test data:

`test_norm = (test_df - df.mean()) / (df.max() - df.min())`

But my data is not normally distributed. It is probably exponentially distributed, with high number of 0s and lower large values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your maximum value of test (ie 10) will not be scaled to 1, but to 0.1 if used properly against learned max and min from training data.

That can be achieved by calling only `min_max_scaler.transform()` on test data. `fit()` or `fit_transform()` is to be used on training data only.

So for training data the code is same:

```
df_train_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df_train.values)
```

But for testing data, it becomes:

```
df_test_scaled = min_max_scaler.transform(df_test.values)
```

This way, the MinMaxScaler will store the max and min values seen during the fit() on the training data and then use them on test data, to properly scale the data.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, the model and the training model are not running on the same machine. Hence I was calling `min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df_train.values)` twice. Instead I will make a pickle dump of `min_max_scaler` and load it into my test model.

Comment: @GRS Yes, thats the proper way. :) Also, you should use joblib to pickle scikit object as recommended here:- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#persistence-example